# Vue's nested routing: parent and children are both displaying

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following routes in my vue app:

```
    { path: '/projects', name: 'ProjectsList', component: ProjectsList, meta: { title: 'List projects' },
    { path: '/projects/:id/edit', name: 'ProjectsEdit', component: ProjectsEdit },
    { path: '/projects/add', name: 'ProjectsAdd', component: ProjectsAdd  },
    { path: '/projects/:id', name: 'ProjectsView', component: ProjectsView },
```

The /projects route shows all projects.
I will also add the route /projects/:id/people which will display the people connected to the project.

I am not using nested routes, obviously. My question is... should I? Or, does it even make sense in a crud? I am especially dubious given that in nested routes in Vue's router BOTH the parent AND the child elements are shown (?!?).

Take for example `/projects/:id`, which will display a project's details. But... if I declare `/projects/:id/edit` as a child of `/projects/:id`, the screen will display BOTH the full element and the editing form.

I am confused. What is the use-case of the routing if this is how it works? Or (likely) I am I getting something really wrong?

Comment: Nested routes are meant for nested components.  ProjectsList can only contain ProjectsEdit if ProjectsList contains its own `<router-view />` element and if the child + parent routes match. If that's the case, then the router-view inside ProjectsList will be replaced with ProjectsEdit, nesting them.  If you want ProjectsList as its own view, and ProjectsEdit as its own view, they should be sibling routes, and whatever the root component is with router-view (usually App.vue) will only display one and not the other.

Comment: [Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) might also help here.